# PHP - I get "Bad Request" Error when using $_GET with strings

Tags: php, string, get, url-parameters

I'm trying to fetch two parameters using $_GET as follows:

**index.php :**

```
<?php

include("../includes/simple_html_dom.php");

echo ("<!-- Written By: Alaa Elrifaie -->\n");

// Fetch user input
$data = htmlspecialchars($_GET["data"]);
$key = htmlspecialchars($_GET["key"]);

// Test if values have been fetched
echo($data . '<br>' . $key);
?>
```

It works fine when passing a single word like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?data=OneWord&key=AlsoOneWord
```

But it gives a "404 Error" when trying to pass a full string:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?data=This is a set of data&key=This is the key!
// This doesn't work
```

How to solve it? As it is neccessary for me to achieve it!

Comment: can you please tell me what does your website do?

Comment: [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your parameters

Comment: 3 lines of code surrounded by credits, made me laugh ;p

Comment: @LozCheroneツ What do you mean?

Comment: @LozCheroneツ Ok, I got it. me too. maybe its their first program

Answer (score 0):

The "Bad Request" (usually a 400 status code) tells you, that you (the client) sent input to the server that couldn't be understood. So there's nothing wrong with your script but with what you're passing to it.

As the comments below your question pointed out, that might be the case because you are sending a wrongly formatted request string to your server. Query parameters (everything after the "?" in the URL) have to be encoded, so instead of

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?data=This is a set of data&key=This is the key!
// This doesn't work
```

you should try

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?data=This%20is%20a%20set%20of%20data&key=This%20is%20the%20key!
// This should work
```

See [this tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) for an online urlencoder/decoder. PHP has a built-in functions for this: [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) encodes spaces as '+' or [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) encodes spaces as '%20' (obeying [RFC3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html))

Comment: Spaces can also be encoded as `+`. Then it becomes `...index.php?data=This+is+a+set+of+data...`

Comment: When I do it using a `url-encoded` parameter it will be converted into a normal parameter ( decoded ) in the browser, giving a 404 error again!

Comment: I've literally no idea what you are talking about.